# Javascript: Hierarchical object sorting

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array of objects and every objects has the fields `id`, `parentId` and `position`.
The position field stores the relative position of that item, so if I make a sort function like this:

```
object.sort((a, b) => {
  if(a.position < b. position) return -1;
  if(a.position > b. position) return 1;
  return 0;
})
```

It ends up like this:

```
{id: 1, parentId: null, position: 0}
{id: 3, parentId: null, position: 1}
{id: 5, parentId: 1, position: 1}
{id: 6, parentId: 3, position: 1}
{id: 4, parentId: null, position: 2}
{id: 2, parentId: 1, position: 2}
```

How to check both parentId and position to end up like this?

```
{id: 1, parentId: null, position: 0}
{id: 5, parentId: 1, position: 1}
{id: 2, parentId: 1, position: 2}
{id: 3, parentId: null, position: 1}
{id: 6, parentId: 3, position: 1}
{id: 4, parentId: null, position: 2}
```

Comment: What is the logic behind expecting `{id: 3, parentId: null, position: 1}` at index 3?

Comment: _"Is there a way..."_ - Yes. Define the logic, reproduce it with JS -> What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: @Nitheesh parent `id: 1`, then all "children" of `id: 1` (by position), next parent (`id: 3`), children of that parent, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could collect all nodes by their `parentId` and get the ordered result starting with `null` and by the ordered arrays.

```js
const
    getNodes = parent => (parents[parent] || [])
        .sort((a, b) => a.position - b.position)
        .flatMap(o => [o, ...getNodes(o.id)]),
    data = [{ id: 1, parentId: null, position: 0 }, { id: 2, parentId: 1, position: 2 }, { id: 3, parentId: null, position: 1 }, { id: 6, parentId: 3, position: 1 }, { id: 4, parentId: null, position: 2 }, { id: 5, parentId: 1, position: 1 }],
    parents = data.reduce((r, o) => ((r[o.parentId] ??= []).push(o), r), {}),
    result = getNodes(null);

console.log(result);
console.log(parents);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```